# meshgrid doesn't work when function contains matrices

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I wanted to plot a surface of a real function of two variables, which
contain matrices, but otherwise the function is real. When I try to run
the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.linalg import expm, norm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm

def f(x,y):
  A = np.array([[0,-1,0],[1,0,0],[0,0,0]])
  v = np.array([[1,2,3]])
  return norm(x*y*A@v.T)

x = np.linspace(-10,10)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,x)
ff = f(xx, yy)

plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, ff, cmap=cm.viridis)
```

I always get:

```
[...]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (50,50) (3,3)
```

Despite all operands are taken care with respect to shape.
What do I have to modify in order that it runs?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know which array(s) is (50,50) and which is (3,3)?  That expression is complicated with multiple places where braodcasting can occur.  Any of of the `-`,`+` and `*`.  Identify the problem operation and arrays.  From that you can decide what needs to be corrected.  We should have to dig through your code to determine those shapes.

Comment: Oh, and correct the function indentation.  Correct indentation is a must for working python code, and highly desirable for readable SO code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
zz = np.array([f(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(xx), np.ravel(yy))]).reshape(xx.shape)
# … further code here … 
surf = ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, zz, cmap=cm.viridis)
```

it will evaluate `f(x,y)` individually for each point and then reshape the array back into the 2D format which is required for `plot_surface()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are multiplying a 3x3 (`a and b variables`) matrix with a 50x50 (`xx and yy`) matrix element wise. Therefore, fix this issue and everything should be okay.

**Example:**

`np.array([1,2,3])*np.array([1,2,3])`

> Output: array([1,4,9])

`np.array([1,2,3])*np.array([1,2,3,4])`

> Output: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,)

Comment: `a` and `b` are matrices, `x` and `y` are real! If you evaluate, say `f(1,2)` you get a real value. How can you use meshgrid in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [83]: x=np.linspace(-10,10)
In [84]: x.shape
Out[84]: (50,)
In [85]: xx,yy=np.meshgrid(x,x)
In [86]: xx.shape
Out[86]: (50, 50)
```

So inside your function `a` (and `b`) is (3,3), will `x` and `y` are (50,50).  `y*b` will produce your error.

What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: But `y` is float! If you evaluate, say `f(1,2)` you get a real value.
How can I use meshgrid in this case?